# Canvas with selectable region of interest, negative coordinates

Tags: python, user-interface, drawing, tkinter

I'd like to draw filled polygons (squares and hexagons) onto a canvas and, later, be able to zoom in or out of the canvas on regions of interest.

I've drafted the following demo program based on Tkinter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

def DrawSquare(canvas, orgx, orgy, size, filler):
  orgx=orgx*size
  orgy=orgy*size
  canvas.create_polygon(orgx, orgy, orgx+size, orgy, orgx+size, orgy+size, orgx, orgy+size, orgx, orgy, outline="black", fill=filler)

def main():
  w = Frame()
  w.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
  canvas = Canvas()
  canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

  for x in range(-30,10):
    for y in range(-30,10):
      DrawSquare(canvas, x,y,20,"white")

  mainloop()

main()
```

It draws a number of squares onto the canvas, but, at least with the default options of the Tkinter canvas, I can't see the squares in the negative quadrants.

The question then is:

- Can Tkinter.Canvas be made to slide and zoom (preferably using built-in functions)?
- Is there an alternative framework I can transition to which is more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

By default the upper left corner is at 0,0. If you want to see something above or to the left you simply need to scroll to that part of the canvas. In order to do that, you should first set the `scrollregion` attribute, so the canvas knows what part of its (pseudo-)infinite space you want to be able to see.

Add the following line of code after drawing all of the objects:

```
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

You can zoom the canvas by calling the [scale](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.scale-method) method, giving it a factor to scale everything in the X and Y direction.